# React-Apollo Query refetch causes children to unmount

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a display component wrapped in a `Query` component to recieve data from a GraphQL query. After I perform a mutation, I have to refetch the data to update the store.  The problem is that calling `refetch()` results in the child component being unmounted, thus disrupting the interaction and scrolling that the user has been doing to cause the mutation.

Is there a way to call `refetch()` without it causing the childen to unmount?  If not, is there better way to the update the store that won't cause an unmount?  Below is the code with the `Query` component and its child.

```
<Query
  query={query}
  variables={{videoId}}
>
  {
    ({loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
      if (loading) 
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return <p>Error :(</p>;
      }

      const onChange = () => {
        console.log("refetching");
        return refetch();
      }

      const {timestampCollection} = data;
      return(
          <TimestampCollection onChange={onChange} player={this.state.player} timestampCollection={timestampCollection[0]} />
      )
    }
  }
</Query>
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: You can pass a `key` prop to your `TimestampCollection`, so that React knows how to deal with it. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `fetchPolicy="network-only"` like below.

```
<Query
  query={query}
  variables={{videoId}}
  fetchPolicy="network-only"
>
```

Comment: And another possibility would be, when refetch is fired, it might set `loading=true` and will destroy the < TimestampCollection> component.

Comment: You can identify refetch by `({loading, error, data, refetch, networkStatus }) => { ...` and check `networkStatus=4` . Please refer https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus